# android : adding SearchView inside a ListView with Custom AdaptEr

Tags: java, android, listview

I have an activity with a custom arraylist that holds 5600 items. The arraylist references a .csv file for the inputs and is linked to a listview for display. What I'm having trouble with is adding a search feature for that listview so the user can narrow their search if they want something more specific. I've tried many other tutorials but nothing seemed to fit my exact scenario. I'd appreciate the help, hope i posted the question properly.

This is the java class for the listview

```
package com.example.android.practiceapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class games extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_games);
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.slots);
        CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);
        List<String[]> slots = csvFile.read();
        MyListAdapter adapter=new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item,R.id.game_title, slots);
        ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class CSVFile {
        InputStream inputStream;

        public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream){
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        public List<String[]> read(){
            //
            List<String[]> resultList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] row = line.split(",");
                    resultList.add(row);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main",e.getMessage());
            }
            finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Main",e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return resultList;
        }
    }

}
```

If needed, the ListViewAapter

```
package com.example.android.practiceapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by swvki on 7/15/2017.
 */
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String[]>{
    int groupid;
    List<String[]> items;
    Context context;
    String path;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int vg, int id, List<String[]> items){
        super(context,vg, id, items);
        this.context=context;
        groupid=vg;
        this.items=items;

    }
    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textid;
        public TextView textname;
        public TextView denom;
        public TextView tech;

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = convertView;
        if(rowView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView= inflater.inflate(groupid, parent, false);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.textid = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.game_title);
            viewHolder.textname = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.location);
            viewHolder.denom = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.denomination);
            viewHolder.tech = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.manufacterer);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        // Fill data
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        String[] row=items.get(position);
        holder.textid.setText(row[0]);
        holder.textname.setText(row[1]);
        holder.denom.setText(row[2]);
        holder.tech.setText(row[3]);

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

This is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context="com.example.android.practiceapp.games">
</ListView>
```